# How to add multiple objects to a foreign table using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am new to Entity Framework. I have two tables called `Polls` and `Candidates` which have a one-to-many relationship.

I want to add multiple candidates to a poll.

This is my code:

```
public bool InsertPolls(PollModel _polls)
{       
        polls = new Poll();
        candidates = new candidate();

        polls.Name = _polls.name;
        polls.startDate = startDate;
        polls.endDate = endDate;
        polls.Type = _polls.pollType;

        foreach (var candidatesID in _polls.candidateID)
        {
            candidates.Person_ID = candidatesID;
            candidates.Poll = polls;
            _dbContext.candidates.Add(candidates);
            _dbContext.SaveChanges();
        }
}
```

But this throws an exception

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code Additional information: The property 'Person_ID' is part of the object's key information and cannot be modified.

Can anyone help me with this? 
Thank You!

Comment: Are you using Code First or DB First?

Comment: i am using DB First

Comment: At what line are you getting the exception?

Comment: OK Can you provide your DB Diagram from EF?

Comment: Please provide the **full** exception message, including any possible `InnerException` messages, too!

Comment: @JasonH this is the DB Diagram https://postimg.org/image/ipi6eaxed/

Comment: @Oluwafemi the exception is due to it try to insert polls table data again.so it duplicate primary key. i want to know is there any way to add multiple object to foreign tables

Comment: @marc_s the exception is due to it try to insert polls table data again.so it duplicate primary key. i want to know is there any way to add multiple object to foreign tables

Comment: Sadly I cannot give a definite answer yet.  There are a few things that are unclear.

1) I would move "candidates = new candidate();" to inside your foreach loop.
2) I am assuming this is a single method inside a larger class as you have variables that are never declared nor assigned any value, such as "candidates", "startDate", "endDate"
3) As @marc_s requested/pointed out, you have only provided the exception type but it would be helpful to have the full exception

Comment: @JasonH this is the exception - 

 **An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The property 'Person_ID' is part of the object's key information and cannot be modified.**

Comment: Right, likely what is going on is the Table's column Person_ID is set to Identity which means the DB is creating new IDs for you when you insert records.  Comment out this line: candidates.Person_ID = candidatesID; and try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for remedy this problem put in first line in the ***for loop*** flowing code

```
candidates = new candidate();
```

also remove ***candidates = new candidate();*** from top of code   .
  the flowing code in ***for loop*** remove too

```
 candidates.Poll = polls;
```

because you have added in the top of code.

this is the final code

```
public bool InsertPolls(PollModel _polls)
{       
    polls = new Poll();

    polls.Name = _polls.name;
    polls.startDate = startDate;
    polls.endDate = endDate;
    polls.Type = _polls.pollType;
    _dbContext.Polls.Add(polls);
    _dbContext.SaveChanges();

    foreach (var candidatesID in _polls.candidateID)
    {
        candidates = new candidate();
        candidates.Person_ID = candidatesID;
        _dbContext.candidates.Add(candidates);
        _dbContext.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```